# should i use mono to develop linux app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mono

I have years of experience developing on microsoft development stack primarily visual studio 2012/c#. But right now, im required to develop app on linux. While i know c++, its been years since i really touch that. I have few questions.

1. Can i develop using mono and compile binary for linux and windows with no code(or minimal) code changes?
2. Can i develop on windows platform using visual studio 2012, compile for linux on window platform? do i need to use virtual machine for compiling for linux in windows platform?
3. How do you setup your development environment if you want to develop linux app on windows platform(develop on windows, compile for linux and windows. my linux box use for testing is a separate machine.)

Some info on what im working on.
My project is about network channel analysis. The client is cheap industrial linux box most probably with no ui. Im using mono/c# to develop the client. The server would be windows develop using vs2012 c#. Most probably using wpf as ui. Im planning to share network/communication library between linux(client) and windows(server). My primary concern for using linux is for cost saving since the client is almost thousand units.

thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is mono still suitable for a Linux Desktop Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614050/is-mono-still-suitable-for-a-linux-desktop-application)

Comment: i dont plan on developing a linux desktop application(i take it as application with gui). i plan to develop a console application in linux since i already know c#.

Comment: then you will not face most of the hurdles that the answers explain about WinForms, WPF and others, just develop your app using VS2012 without using P/Invokes, and it will work on Linux

Answer (score 4):

Mono runs executables in PE (Portable Executable) format, the native file format of Windows. There's no need to "compile for Linux", as long as your app is pure MSIL. And even if you use native DLLs through p/invoke, Mono and Wine work together to run the Windows files on Linux.

(The a.out and ELF executable formats used by native Linux applications don't have mechanisms for storing .NET metadata, the PE format was modified to support .NET, so that's what .NET Framework (not Micro Framework) implementations use regardless of platform)

Comment: More information about Mono+Wine can be found at http://wiki.winehq.org/Mono, but it is not a good idea IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

The most important things to consider at the beginning are,

- WinForms of Mono is problematic. Not only most third party controls won't work properly, but also libgdiplus itself is not 100% compatible with Microsoft's GDI+. It might appear to be a sweet option, but later you might still need to fight hard against the incompatibilities.
- WPF is not an option as Mono does not support it yet.
- GTK# is your best choice for UI, which blends naturally with Linux distros. If you refactor your Windows project properly, you should be able to share the non-UI code between your Windows and Linux solutions. This is what Mono guys recommend (not only use native UI frameworks for Windows, Linux, but also for Mac/MonoMac, iOS/Xamarin.iOS, and Android/Xamarin.Android).

So go back to your questions,

1. You should never wish for no code change for a real world project. No, that's impossible. As I said earlier, you have a chance to share most non-UI portion.
2. You can develop the non-UI portion and the Windows only portion using VS2012 and test them out on Windows. If you plan to use Mono's WinForms or GTK#, you must develop and debug on Linux using MonoDevelop. Thus, you need either a virtual machine or physical machine of Linux.
3. For me, I frequently switch between Linux/MonoDevelop and Windows/VS.

As Mono + C# is much more productive than using C/C++, many successful Linux apps are developed on Mono, such as Banshee and Tomboy.

Comment: Thank you for the invaluable insight. My project is about network channel analysis. The client is cheap industrial linux box most probably with no ui. Im using mono/c# to develop the client. The server would be windows develop using vs2012 c#. Most probably using wpf as ui. Im planning to share network/communication library between linux(client) and windows(server). My primary concern for using linux is for cost saving since the client is almost thousand units. What is your opinion on this matter? What would you do if you were me? Thanks.

Comment: If your app planned for Linux is a simple console application (Linux service apps are normally also console based, different from Windows service apps), then I think you can fully utilize VS to write it, and then test out on Linux. However, due to the difference of Mono CLR and .NET CLR, sometimes you might still need to prepare a Linux development machine (virtual/physical) aside, in case you need to perform some Mono only debugging.

Comment: Why not make web UI? These days you can make it pretty rich, and it'll be quite cross-platform.

Comment: Web based UI performance is limited by the web browser core you wrap. If you really want to develop a complex UI, native controls/DirectX/OpenGL can give you better result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio without problems but for example you cannot use WPF, while Windows Forms are ok. For more information what you can use visit: http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility

Moreover there exists Mono tools which integrates with VS: http://www.mono-project.com/GettingStartedWithMonoTools

Comment: Windows Forms might appear to be an option, but should not be recommended for application migration generally due to so many incompatibilities among .NET WinForms and Mono's implementation. BTW, Mono Tools for VS is no longer available publicly. The link on the page you refer to in fact link to Xamarin's products for iOS and Android.

Comment: @LexLi so the only option now is MonoDevelop?

Comment: I rather say "the only option if you want to design the UI for GTK# and debug into Mono" is MonoDevelop. Those are the things you cannot do with VS, though in VS you can write non-UI code.